# Ember "select" View deadlocks platform.js when content array provided by Controller?

Tags: ember.js, polyfills, htmlbars

I'm working on migrating a non-CLI Ember app to 1.10 with HTMLBars. In a View Template I have a select list rendered by Ember.Select View where it's content is obtained from an array property in the Controller (adultsSelect: (1).upto(4)). I changed 'Ember.Select' to '"select"' as the updated docs suggest. As soon as I setup the 'view select' with 'content=adultsSelect', the browser deadlocks, I'm prompted to stop, debug or continue line 13 in 'platform.js'. If I go into 'debug', I don't know what I'm debugging, but I see a sort of infinite recursion of calls or references to 'platform.js'. If I change the array assignment to just 'adultsSelect: ["1","2"]', there's no improvement. 'Platform.js' is a product of the Polymer project which has something to do with upcoming web components technologies which Ember is using in advance. However, Polymer now says that 'web components polyfills' were released in the past as 'platform.js' so seems I'm already out-of-date with this. It's funny that something as simple as a select list with 4 options can be so complex in Ember that when you go to migrate to a new version, your browser locks up, doesn't tell you why, there's no docs to say this will happen and what to do about it, but that an obsolete version of an upcoming technology being used in advance is somehow involved in it. Should I look for a bower dependency related to web components and update that so I get a compatible version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I simply removed 'platform.js' as a script linked into 'index.html' and now select lists work, at least in the development build running on node express.